# AppleScript and MD5

Tags: shell, command, applescript, md5

I'm simply trying to compute the MD5 of a string using AppleScript:

```
set hash_string to do shell script "echo -n hi | md5"
```

In the code above, I've actually replaced the string passed to shell with "hi" as a test.  AppleScript reports:

```
tell current application
    do shell script "echo -n hi | md5"
        --> "5ea3a74c5a5c60abd09da8c5f85fa0a5"
end tell
```

Running the same command directly in a terminal results in:

```
% echo -n hi | md5
49f68a5c8493ec2c0bf489821c21fc3b
```

Though the command is identical, the computed hash is different.  Obviously, additional characters are being passed in AppleScript, but I can't seem to figure out what they are.  I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 5):

You can see what is happening if you remove the `| md5`.  In the AppleScript case, you'll see `-n hi` as output.  That's because the POSIX `sh` `echo`, which is invoked by `do shell script`, does not support `-n` whereas the `bash` or `csh` `echo` builtins or the `/bin/echo` command all do support `-n`.

```
$ bash
$ echo -n hi
hi$ sh
$ echo -n hi
-n hi
```

See the [Mac OS X `echo` man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/echo.1.html) or the [POSIX documentation for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) for more info. Note, POSIX compliance *requires* that conforming implementations of `echo` must *not* support any options including `-n`; for compatibility across shells and systems, the POSIX editors suggest using `printf` to do things like suppressing newlines.

```
tell current application
    do shell script "printf '%s' hi | md5"
end tell
--> "49f68a5c8493ec2c0bf489821c21fc3b"
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  That makes complete sense.

Comment: Glad it helped.  BTW, welcome to SO. If you ask a question here, it's expected that you'll either mark an answer as accepted or revise your question until you do get an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you drop the -n from the echo command, then it should work fine. Not totally sure why... but that seems to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
set passwordPlain to "hi"
set foo to do shell script "/sbin/md5 -qs" & passwordPlain
return foo
```

this results and the same as

```
 echo -n hi | md5
```

from command prompt